# External database connection error in magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Here is my function for external database connection
and using connection factory class to create connection, it is working fine in 2.3.3.
//use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\ConnectionFactory;

```
public function getConnection(){    
 $db = $this->connectionFactory->create(
            [
                'host' => XX.XXX.XXX.X,
                'dbname' => 'dbname',
                'username' => 'username',
                'password' => 'password',
                'active' => '1',
            ]
        );
    return $db;
}
```

However when i tested it in 2.3.4 i am getting this error

```
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Note: host is external IP of the database that i am using to connect.

Comment: Host name was not coming correctly,once I fixed the host name it started work

Answer (score 0):

it looks like to me that you tried to access the database as root which is not allowed. Are you running the db inside of a docker container?

Answer (score 0):

Host name was not coming correctly,once I fixed the host name it started work